# What does \ mean in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift.

I'm pretty sure I understand what \ does in code like:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
```

```
ForEach(example, id: \.id) {
//etc.
}
```

But what does \ actually mean? Is there some way to memorise it in your head in a meaningful way?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md#why-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is swift KeyPath

```
struct Guitar {
    let model: String
    let year: Int
}
let gibson = Guitar(model: "Gibson", year: 1990)
let path = \Guitar.model /// KeyPath<Guitar, String>

print(gibson[keyPath: path])
// prints “Gibson”
```

Example take and you can read more details in https://medium.com/@jllnmercier/swift-keypaths-db326852d66a

and search keywords "swift keypath"

For your snapshot

```
ForEach(example, id: \.id) {
//etc.
}
```

it means that `ForEach` will use `example.Element.id` as identifier for each iterated row.

Comment: I see, so the \ is like the 'Root' of something like the 'root of a directory' kind of thing? and saying `\.id` in the for each is the equivalent of `example.id`? What does `Element` refer to?

Comment: If `example`, for instance, is-a `[Item]`, then `Element` is `Item` (which expected to be `Identifiable`), so `\.id` is `Item.id`

Comment: Oh I understand. yeah example is an array of items. Thanks this is very helpful. So for `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)`, what root would \ be referring to?

Comment: `extension EnvironmentValues { public var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext }`